# iOS NSArray Sorting

Tags: ios, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I have a nested array and want to sort it by a key present inside the inner array.
below given is my array which I want to sort using `NSSortDescriptor` or in other way.

```
fares(
{
    pid = 1;
    type1 = (
    {
        color = "red";
        size = "big";
        properties = (
        {
            mod = "auto";
            payment = "EMI";
            moresegs = (
            {
                id = 141;
                name = "abcd";
                duration = "1 year"
            })
        })
    });
    type2 = (
    {
        color = "green";
        size = "small";
        properties = (
        {
            mod = "auto";
            payment = "EMI";
            moresegs = (
            {
                id = 141;
                name = "abcd";
                duration = "1 year"
            })
        })
    })
}

{
    pid = 1;
    type1 = (
    {
        color = "red";
        size = "big";
        properties = (
        {
            mod = "auto";
            payment = "EMI";
            moresegs = (
            {
                id = 141;
                name = "abcd";
                duration = "1 year"
            })
        })
    });
    type2 = (
    {
        color = "green";
        size = "big";
        properties = (
        {
            mod = "auto";
            payment = "EMI";
            moresegs = (
            {
                id = 141;
                name = "abcd";
                duration = "1 year"
            })
        })
    })
})
```

How can i sort above array using key **"type2->properties->payment"**?

-------update-----------

I modified the array and used NSSortDescriptor which solved my problem

Comment: Please format your code. Unlike computers, us humans can't read random splurges of text. It isn't hard to format correctly. Just do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"type1.size" ascending:YES];
NSArray *finalArray = [self.firstArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

Comment: @PrafulKadam just replace "type1.size" from this answer with "type2.properties.payment". This will sort the array how you want.

Comment: The questions was edited I think. As @Fogmeister mentioned, change "type1.size" to "type2.properties.payment"

Comment: -[__NSArrayI compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x825f410

Answer (score 0):

Try this by inputing the fares array into this method-

```
+(NSArray*)sortedListBySize:(NSArray*)_unsortedList{
    NSArray *sortedListBySize = [_unsortedList sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)^(id obj1, id obj2){

        if ([[obj1 valueForKeyPath:@"type2.properties.payments" ] intValue] < [[obj1 valueForKeyPath:@"type2.properties.payments"] intValue]) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        } else if ([[obj1 valueForKeyPath:@"type2.properties.payments" ] intValue] > [[obj1 valueForKeyPath:@"type2.properties.payments"] intValue]) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }];
    return sortedListBySize;
}
```

Comment: payments is not an intvalue-> that was my assumption. Thats why I wrote [payment(NSString) intValue]. You need not use it then- just use [obj1 valueForKeyPath:@"type2.properties.payments"] <.

Comment: tried this but it is sorting randomly and not by payments key

Comment: I was actually thinking payments  as quantity. You will have to specify the kind of sort you need here.

Comment: ok suppose it is duration like "10:00", "02:30",..... in this case how can i sort can you please explain. I am trying to solve this since long time

Comment: You will have to construct NSDate objects from these strings and compare them within the block. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it